# Not getting whole data while using available()

Tags: java, inputstream

I m not getting the whole data sometimes  while reading the inputStream like this(somtime full data is recieved).

```
 private String readInputStream(InputStream in) {
            PushbackInputStream inputStream = (PushbackInputStream) in;
            StringBuffer outputBuffer = null;
            try {
                int size = inputStream.available();
                    outputBuffer = new StringBuffer(size);
                    // append the data into the stringBuilder
                    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                        int ch = inputStream.read();
                        outputBuffer.append((char) ch);
                    }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e("error", "IOException: " +
                        ioe.getMessage());
            }
            if (outputBuffer != null) {
                return outputBuffer.toString();
        }
```

should i read the input Stream until inputStream.available() is zero..?Data in inputStream is large.Plz Suggest some altenative with Sample code

Comment: You should read until `read()` returns -1. Why are you casting to `PushbackInputStream` anyway? Additionally, this approach to converting to text assumes an encoding of ISO-8859-1 - is that definitely correct for your data? Usually you should use an `InputStreamReader` to perform the conversion for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `available().` See the Javadoc. It isn't anything to do with 'size', only with what can currently be read *without blocking.* And that can be as little as zero bytes.

You should read until end of stream, or until you have a complete message, or line, or document, or whatever it is you're reading.

And as you're not making any use of the `PushbackInputStream` in this code, it is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: input stream is of HTTP

Comment: @ManasL So you need to read the HTTP headers and then the body. If you're using `URL` and `URLConnection` as you should be, all you have to do is read until end of stream: the software will take care of the content length etc for you. If you're reading a socket directly you have a small world of pain ahead of you as you implement (a) HTTP 1.0, (b) HTTP 1.1 with keepalive and the Content-length header, and (c) chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: I get the input Stream from NANOhttpd's IHTTPSession.getInputStream

Comment: so do i need to take care of the things you hav mentioned.?